# When dynamically creating input fields, <select> filled with $.each only once, why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, append, each

I try to dynamically add an input field to a form. It works fine except one thing:

I try to fill a  with $.each, but this only works for the first dynamically added  if I add more, the  stays empty..

the #add button is in the initial form:

**append**:

```
    $('#add').click(function() {
        i++;
        $dynamic_field').append('' +
        '<h1>Sensor '+i+'</h1>   ' +
        '<tr id="row'+i+'">
        '<td><div class="form-group">\n' +
                 '<label for="InputSensorType">Sensor Type*</label>\n' +
                  '<select class="form-control" id="InputSensorType" name="sensorType[]"></select>\n' 
         '</div></td>\n +'
         '<td>
              <button type="button" name="copy" id="copy" class="btn btn-primary">Copy this sensor
              </button></td><tr>');
```

Each:

```
          var jsarray = <?php echo json_encode($sensors)?>;

           $.each(jsarray, function (index, value) {
               $('#InputSensorType').append(('<option value='+index+'>'+value+'</option>'));
           });
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements that have the same ID (InputSensorType), that's probably the issue here. You will have to change it to a class, and refer to it as $('.InputSensorType')

Comment: `$dynamic_field` is static on the client. Also, where is `jsarray` updated?

Comment: On top of the page jsarray is updated by a for loop reading elements from an excel file and putting them in the array. if I use class instead of ID i get an error: jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1953' in [*all array values*]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var jsarray = '<?php echo json_encode($sensors)?>';
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsarray);
var data = '';
 $.each(jsarray, function (index, value) {               
           data +='<option value='+index+'>'+value+'</option>';
            });
 $('#InputSensorType').append(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply: If I put this I get: VM407:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 896 at the obj var, if I remove that var it still only shows on the first added form